# ¿como colocar icono (shorcut icon) en DOMPDF?

Tags: pdf

Estoy empezando con esta librería y no he podido colocar el icono de la empresa al momento de ser ejecutado la librería.

> Archivo PHP

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
ob_get_clean();
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
    $options = new Options();
        $options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
        $options->set('isPhpEnabled', true);
        $options->set('isJavascriptEnabled', true);
        $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
        $dompdf->loadHtml(file_get_contents('cabezal.html'));
        // $dompdf->setPaper([0, 0, 2550, 3300]);
        $dompdf->setPaper([0, 0, 740, 1175]);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream('pdf', ['Attachment' => 0]);
```

> Archivo HTML

```
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible"/>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>

    <link href="vistas/css/images/fede3.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"/>
                          ↑↑↑ No muestra el icono ↑↑↑

    <title>
        FEDERACION.
    </title>
    <!-- Default theme -->
    <body>
        <p>
            hola
        </p>
    </body>
</head>
```

Y cuando envió un GET por medio del navegador para traerme el icono lo trae y usando la misma ruta que le tengo al `<link>`. En vez de eso muestra el icono de XAMPP.

¿Que puede ser?

Comment: Alguna veces ocurre que el **caché del navegador** oculta la presencia del icono. Pruebe a borrarlo antes de buscar errores que posiblemente no existan.

Comment: No, no funciona.

Comment: Qué intentaste? @Angel Zambrano, Borraste el caché del navegador? - Si usas algún framework es posible que también tenga un caché que deba ser borrardo.

Comment: Suele ser necesario cerrar, o abandonar, la página antes de borrar el cache y luego recargarla desde pestaña nueva o ventana nueva usando la dirección, (no volver atrás, ni aceptar las direcciones emergentes) y eventualmente, pinchar algunas veces F5 para poder ver el cambio

Comment: Lamentablemente sigue el mismo icono del XAMPP y he buscado en otros foros y nada.

Comment: Hay otra posibilidad, tal vez no estas usando el tipo mime correcto. Acabo de recordar que para las nuevas versiones de php hubo cambios significativos en las cadenas de declaración (al identificarlos) y eso tiene impacto al pasarlas a los elementos html. **Prueba: type="image/x-icon"** así paso algunos .png que uso en mis sitios

Comment: Otra verificación necesaria: **el path a la imagen** puede estar apuntando al vacío. Iserta un contenedor de imagen con la misma dirección en src para establecer si se está escribiendo correctamente o no. Es muy posible que debas escribir href="/tusitio/vistas/css/images/fede3.png"

Comment: Como escribí antes, usé un XMLHttpRequest .open('get','vistas/css/images/fede3.png')... y recibí la imagen...

Comment: Probaste cambiar el tipo mime? Si la dirección es correcta, puede ser eso. Usa image/x-icon yo lo uso para algunos .png

Comment: Lo tengo como "<link rel="shortcut icon" href="vistas/css/images/fede3.png" type="image/x-icon" />" y nada, ¿lo estoy colocando mal?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79358/discussion-between-quevedo-and-angel-zambrano). Por favor pincha el enlace para entrar